# Default parameter to a method, of method?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a sourcecode, but i have a problem with that.

You can find the source code right here: http://pastebin.com/6JHkTFEv

Error is here: http://i.imgur.com/V4pPZkI.png

Why gives me always this error message?

The problem is within this row:

```
public function upload_sms_data( $sms_id, $prefix, $uzenet, $telefonszam, $kategoria, $ip_address = $this->get_client_ip()) {
```

The program is stopped by the last parameter: `$ip_address = $this->get_client_ip()`

Can I give a default parameter to a method, of method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value of an argument to be the result of a function call. It has to be a value.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. the best thing to do would be to have `null` as the default and then inside the method if that param is null then use the getter.

```
upload_sms_data( $sms_id, $prefix, $uzenet, $telefonszam, $kategoria, $ip_address = null ) { 
   $ip_address = $ip_address === null ? $this->get_client_ip() : $ip_address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a default value, but not one that requires run-time calculation or execution such as the result of a function call

```
public function upload_sms_data( $sms_id, $prefix, $uzenet, $telefonszam, $kategoria, $ip_address = NULL ) { 
    if ($ip_address === NULL) {
        $ip_address = $this->get_client_ip();
    }
```